# taking the natural log of $\mathrm{e}^{2x} =\frac{4}{3} $

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have been unable to answer the following question.

I must solve for $x$:

$$e^{2x} = \frac{4}{3}$$

I have been made aware that I must take the natural logarithm at both sides, giving:

$$\ln(\mathrm{e}^{2x}) = \ln\left( \frac{4}{3} \right)$$

The solution is : $$x = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln\left( \frac{4}{3} \right)$$

I am not sure how my tutor has arrived at this point.

If anyone could show me how to solve it giving more steps then it would be very much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: "I have been made aware that I must take the natural log of both sides". Why? Once you figure that out, the missing step is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, a few things:

- $$\log_a(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$$
- $$\ln(e)=\log_e(e)=\frac{\ln(e)}{\ln(e)}=1$$
- $$\ln(x)=\log_e(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(e)}=\frac{\ln(x)}{1}=\ln(x)$$
- $$\ln(a^x)=x\ln(a)\space\space\space\text{when}\space a,x\space\text{are positive}$$
- $$\ln\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)=\ln(a)-\ln(x)\space\space\space\text{when}\space a,x\space\text{are positive}$$

So, solving your question:

$$e^{2x}=\frac{4}{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left(e^{2x}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2x\ln\left(e\right)=\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2x\cdot1=\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2x=\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{\ln(4)-\ln(3)}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{\ln(2^2)-\ln(3)}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{2\ln(2)-\ln(3)}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\ln(2)-\frac{\ln(3)}{2}\approx0.1438410362$$

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for a step by step guide, and additional relevant information. I appreciate the time you have taken to cover the question comprehensively .

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$\ln(a^x)=x\ln(a)$

Thus
$$ln(e^{2x}) = ln(4/3)$$
$$(2x)ln(e) = ln(4/3)$$
$$2x = ln(4/3)$$
since $\ln(e)=1$
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{4}{3})$$

Comment: Thank you, this has certainly cleared things up for me.